What's Hibernate cache invalidation mechanism?
Consider two users Alex and John. Both request the same Contract object contract1 simultaneously. contract1 is then cached in 1st level cache in both Alex's and John's sessions. Alex starts a transaction and makes an update to contract1 and commits it. What happens to John's contract1 if John queries contract1 again right after Alex commits his update? How does Hibernate detects that contract1 in John's 1st level cache is inconsistent with its respective state in the database? How does it detect first the change made to the database and propagate it back to the cache and thus to John?
Remind you the 2nd level cache is disabled (by default).
